# Using a single email field to navigate to login if account exists or else to sign up

Tags: login, sign-in, signup

Are there any usability studies on the preference for the following Login/Sign up scenario.

On the first page of the mobile application, you will see a field to enter the email address. If the email address already exists as an account it navigates to the login page, otherwise to the sign up page.

Popular apps that use this mechanism is Uber.

Answer (score 0):

The following scenario is quite common.
I would recommend comparing this scenario with best practices and designing it based on the next suggestions:

1. [Anatomy of a Good vs. Bad Sign Up Form](https://uxmovement.com/forms/anatomy-of-a-good-vs-bad-sign-up-form/)
2. [16 Innovative UX Practices to Simplify Logins](https://uxmovement.com/forms/16-innovative-ux-practices-to-simplify-logins/)
3. [Sign-up form best practices](https://web.dev/sign-up-form-best-practices/#federated-login)

Also, please confirm the scenario with your development team (the development stack may have some technical limitations) and of course with the users ([Jakob's low](https://lawsofux.com/jakobs-law/)).

Comment: Thanks @roman , but your answer does not cater my answer nor the links... Can you help me a bit further...